# How do I run a code from pastebin or JS file in Browser's Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I'm making a Javascript meant to be run from a Browser's Console.
I want to make them as short as possible when pasting to the
console (The code has 299 lines, by the way.). So, I uploaded the code into Pastebin and also to a file hosting which directly goes into the JS file.

The question is,
**How do I run the script from the Pastebin or the JS file in the Console?.**

Comment: You have to create a `<script>` element, append it to `<body>`, then set its `src` to the script's URL. Something like `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<script src="..."></script>');` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to inject it via browser addon. I use tampermonkey for Chrome, which has a simple UI and all features that I need.

Comment: No, um. I was planning to gave this script executable with my friends too. They are not a tech guy, which means It'll make it more complicated if they have to install another software.